# Slice page and reveal div (like slide up and down together)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create an affect which is like the page being sliced horizontally and opens up.
It then pushes the content above it up and the content below down.

So it's abit like jquery slideup 50% and slidedown 50%... however I can't find the jquery effect anywhere so I'm wondering if it's at all possible?

Or whether I need to do a slidedown, then scroll to at the same time which might create a similar effect.

Another designer designed this!!
All help is very much appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI's [Clip](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Clip) effect may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this effect with `.slideDown()` of the center section together with a second simultaneous animation that adjusts the window's scroll position.

The second animation could be :

- `.slideUp()` some sacrificial section at the top of the document, exactly half the height of the center section
- `$('html,body').animate(`scrollTop`, ....)`